# Windows Communicate between process in C

Tags: c, windows, signals

I am attempting to create a program that will sleep for a specified amount of time. A second program will "inform" the first program something has changed. If the second program does not "inform" the sleep ends and other computations happen.

This is trivial for Linux with signals. Is there some similar system for window.

Thanks

Comment: Use a named event object.  Search for CreateEvent.

Comment: in windows this is also trivial. exist many way. say create named event and then first program wait on it with [WaitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) and second can call [SetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Super helpful thanks i think this is my solution!